# Angular: Disable button in template if all values in array are false

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Im looking for a simple yet efficient way to achieve this in template.

The code is as follows:

```
studentArray = Array<boolean>;

<button class="btn btn-success" 
[disabled]="" 
click="generateMarksheet()">
Generate Marksheet 
</button>
```

This button should remain disabled if every value in studentArray is false. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Something along the lines of: `[disabled]={studentArray.every(val => !val)}` or `[disabled]={!studentArray.some(val => val)}`?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl, not working. Getting error in console. It is Angular 6 btw

Comment: It was just pseudocode.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the easiest way to achieve this is to create a method in your `ts` file that will check if all the values are false.

For example :

```js
private youArr: boolean[];

public areAllValuesFalse(): boolean {
  return this.youArr.every(element => element === false)
}
```

You can then bind the method in your template :

```
<button class="btn btn-success" 
   [disabled]="areAllValuesFalse()" 
   click="generateMarksheet()">
   Generate Marksheet 
</button>
```

---

*Note :* If you want to check for falsy values, you can then use `!element` instead of `element === false`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in the Template it could look like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" 
   [disabled]="!studentArray.includes(true)" 
   click="generateMarksheet()">
   Generate Marksheet 
</button>
```

Comment: getting error in console. Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes') it's angular 6 btw

Comment: Thats because your Array is not yet declared. It would work if you'd assign some values to your Array :)